# Performing calculations by subsets of data in R

Tags: r, foreach, subset

I want to perform calculations for each company number in the column PERMNO of my data frame, the summary of which can be seen here:

```
> summary(companydataRETS)
     PERMNO           RET           
 Min.   :10000   Min.   :-0.971698  
 1st Qu.:32716   1st Qu.:-0.011905  
 Median :61735   Median : 0.000000  
 Mean   :56788   Mean   : 0.000799  
 3rd Qu.:80280   3rd Qu.: 0.010989  
 Max.   :93436   Max.   :19.000000
```

My solution so far was to create a variable with all possible company numbers

```
compns <- companydataRETS[!duplicated(companydataRETS[,"PERMNO"]),"PERMNO"]
```

And then use a foreach loop using parallel computing which calls my function get.rho() which in turn perform the desired calculations

```
rhos <- foreach (i=1:length(compns), .combine=rbind) %dopar% 
      get.rho(subset(companydataRETS[,"RET"],companydataRETS$PERMNO == compns[i]))
```

I tested it for a subset of my data and it all works. The problem is that I have 72 million observations, and even after leaving the computer working overnight, it still didn't finish.

I am new in R, so I imagine my code structure can be improved upon and there is a better (quicker, less computationally intensive) way to perform this same task (perhaps using apply or with, both of which I don't understand). Any suggestions?

Comment: Obligatory comment referencing the [data.table](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) package.

Comment: Don't have a good answer for your main question, but your unique list of company names is probably easier to get as `unique(companydataRETS$PERMNO)`

Comment: @joran I will have a look at the data.table package.

Comment: @joran, I installed data.table and modified the code to use it, and the results of system.time() reduced from (43.925  12.413  56.337) using foreach to (0.229   0.047   0.276) using data.table. This is unbelievable! Really what I was looking for. Do you think you can post an answer to my question? I can complete it later with the code modifications, but I would like the points to go to you...

Comment: sorry, I meant using subset vs. data.table.

Comment: No need, all I contributed was the pointer. Post the code yourself with the timing comparison and award the points to yourself. I have plenty. :)

Comment: @Vivi If you'd like to show your appreciation you can also click 'I use this!' on the [Crantastic data.table page](http://crantastic.org/packages/data-table). That's much appreciated by the developers. See [FAQ 6.4](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by [Joran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324364/joran), I looked into the library `data.table`. The modifications to the code are

```
library(data.table) 
companydataRETS <- data.table(companydataRETS)
setkey(companydataRETS,PERMNO)

rhos <- foreach (i=1:length(compns), .combine=rbind) %do% 
      get.rho(companydataRETS[J(compns[i])]$RET)
```

I ran the code as I originally had (using `subset`) and once using `data.table`, with the variable `compns` comprising of only 30 of the 28659 companies in the dataset. Here are the outputs of `system.time()` for the two versions:

Using `subset`:

> user........ system..... elapsed
>    43.925 ... 12.413......  56.337

Using `data.table`

> user....... system..... elapsed
>     0.229.....   0.047.......   0.276

(For some reason using `%do%` instead of `%dopar%` for the original code made it ran faster. The `system.time()` for `subset` is the one using `%do%`, the faster of the two in this case.)

I had left the original code running overnight and it hadn't finished after 5 hours, so I gave up and killed it. With this small modification I had my results in less than 5 minutes (I think about 3 mins)!

EDIT

There is an even easier way to do it using `data.table`, without the use of `foreach`, which involves substituting the last line of the code above by

```
rhos <- companydataRETS[ , get.rho(RET), by=PERMNO]
```

Comment: Glad it worked out. If you can provide more details of the clash you don't understand (e.g. the error message) then we can help. Please do check latest live [NEWS](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&root=datatable) first (also linked at the top of `?data.table`) to see if the problem has already been reported and fixed. Otherwise, please ask a new question about that. It doesn't ring any bells with me.

Comment: @MatthewDowle , the error messages were the same as the error I got previously when trying to use the library doMC after having used `source()` to load some of my functions. I tried to reproduce the error now and it didn't happen. It was probably something unrelated to `data.table`. I will edit my answer above to remove the comment and if it happens again I will post another question. BTW, I did the crantastic thing you suggested above.

Comment: The speed of `%do%` vs. `%dopar%` depends on what your parallel backend is, I think - running things in parallel has all of the overhead of splitting up data, assigning it to different nodes, and recombining.  If you don't have a lot of nodes for parallel processing or if the function you're applying is very simple, it can sometimes be slower than just `%do%`.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do something like this and your `foreach` solution is one of them. Only looking at the code you supplied, I can only guess at the most appropriate solution...

However, I assume the biggest slowdown in your code is actually your `get.rho` function not the looping or subsetting.  If you'd like to share that function, I bet you'll get some amazing answers that will both speed things up and clarify some "R-isms".

With that said, there are also many alternatives to doing what you're doing.

The `plyr` package is tailor made for this type of computation.  It uses a split-apply-combine strategy.  The first two letters of the function indicate the input and output data types.

Since you're inputting a data.frame and outputting a data.frame, `ddply` is the function to use:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(companydataRETS, .(PERMNO), summarise, get.rho(RET))
```

If you're on not windows, you can easily multithread this calc using

```
library(doMC)
registerDoMC()
ddply(companydataRETS, .(PERMNO), summarise, get.rho(RET), .parallel=TRUE)
```

`tapply` is also a perfect candidate:

```
tapply(companydataRETS$RET, companydataRET$PERMNO, get.rho)
```

The `data.table` package, as mentioned in the comments is also excellent at this, but I'll leave that code as an exercise to the reader.

However as I said above, if your `get.rho` function is slow, no matter how clever you get with your subsetting and looping technique, the calculations will take a long time.

---

edit for function code in post:

If this is time series data, or data that can be treated as such, there are many packages and functions that do this sort of lag comparison.  I'm not very well versed in them, but a quick perusal of google and CRAN task views will give you an excellent overview of your options.

I haven't benchmarked it, but I think its safe to assume the slowest section of your code is in the `lm` call.  Doing this on a `sample` of your data instead of the full set will speed things up dramatically.  But I'm sure someone out there will have a much better and more complete solution.

Comment: I am not using windows, but I am using doMC for the parallel computing. My function get.rho() is horrible, and can certainly be improved. I will include it in the main question.

Comment: -1 for suggesting plyr for a 72 million row dataset. Specifically for saying that plyr is tailor made for this?

Comment: @MatthewDowle fair enough.  I intended it as an exercise in possibilities rather than a perfect answer.  But, you're correct that 72 million rows in `plyr` is a horrible horrible idea.