# using data.table with multiple threads in R

Tags: multithreading, r, data.table, apply

Is there a way to utilize multiple threads for computation using `data.table` in R? For example let's say i have the following `data.table`:

```
dtb <- data.table(id=rep(1:10000, 1000), x=1:1e7)
setkey(dtb, id)
f <- function(m) { #some really complicated function }
res <- dtb[,f(x), by=id]
```

Is there a way to get R to multithread this if `f` takes a while to compute? What about in the case that `f` is quick, will multithreading help or is most of the time going to be taken by `data.table` in splitting things up into groups?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure that this is "multi-threading", but perhaps you meant to include a multi-core solution? If so, then look at this earlier answer: [Performing calculations by subsets of data in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210422/performing-calculations-by-subsets-of-data-in-r) found with a search for "[r] [data.table] parallel"

Edit: (doubling of speed on a 4 core machine, but my system monitor suggests this only used 2 cores during the `mclapply` call.) Code copied from this thread: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Access-to-local-variables-in-quot-j-quot-expressions-tt2315330.html#a2315337

```
 calc.fake.dt.mclapply <- function (dt) {
     mclapply(6*c(1000,1:4,6,8,10),
              function(critical.age) {
                  dt$tmp <-  pmax((dt$age <  critical.age) * dt$x, 0)
                  dt[, cumsum.lag(tmp), by = grp]$V1})
 } 
 mk.fake.df <- function (n.groups=10000, n.per.group=70) {
    data.frame(grp=rep(1:n.groups, each=n.per.group),
               age=rep(0:(n.per.group-1), n.groups),
               x=rnorm(n.groups * n.per.group),
               ## These don't do anything, but only exist to give
               ## the table a similar size to the real data.
               y1=rnorm(n.groups * n.per.group),
               y2=rnorm(n.groups * n.per.group),
               y3=rnorm(n.groups * n.per.group),
               y4=rnorm(n.groups * n.per.group)) } 
 df <- mk.fake.df 
 df <- mk.fake.df()
 calc.fake.dt.lapply <- function (dt) { # use base lapply for testing
     lapply(6*c(1000,1:4,6,8,10),
            function(critical.age) {
                dt$tmp <-  pmax((dt$age <  critical.age) * dt$x, 0)
                dt[, cumsum.lag(tmp), by = grp]$V1})
 } 
 mk.fake.dt <- function (fake.df) {
    fake.dt <- as.data.table(fake.df)
    setkey(fake.dt, grp, age)
    fake.dt
  } 
 dt <- mk.fake.dt()

require(data.table)
dt <- mk.fake.dt(df)

 cumsum.lag <- function (x) {
    x.prev <- c(0, x[-length(x)])
    cumsum(x.prev)
  } 
 system.time(res.dt.mclapply <- calc.fake.dt.mclapply(dt))
  user  system elapsed 
 1.896   4.413   1.210 

system.time(res.dt.lapply   <- calc.fake.dt.lapply(dt))
   user  system elapsed 
  1.391   0.793   2.175
```

Comment: unnless i missed something they seem to suggesting using plyr with multiple cores which is unfortunately still much much slower than data.table... i didn't see anything with a data.table solution and multicore...

Comment: Were you looking at the second or the first answer. The first one did not use 'plyr' and did use `foreach` (which is a multi-core function).

Comment: they then write: There is an even easier way to do it using data.table, without the use of foreach, which involves substituting the last line of the code above by

`rhos <- companydataRETS[ , get.rho(RET), by=PERMNO]`

Comment: If you are satisfied with the speed of a non-parallelized approach, then why ask the question?

Comment: i'm not: from their answer it sounds like they said that `data.table` was as fast as the `foreach` approach..

Comment: i found this also helpful: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Parallelize-data-table-s-operations-td2537545.html

Comment: I took it to mean that it was syntactically more compact, rather than faster. I've offered my timing comparisons. You should do your own.

Comment: i see, this is much more clear now. thank you.  i will give multicore a try

Comment: @Alex Glad DWin has sorted you out. [FR#1241](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1242&group_id=240&atid=978) has been outstanding for a while to _Document multicore and other parallel use of data.table_. In the meantime, as DWin correctly showed, it's a case of searching for the discussions to see how it's done. A few more are found by [searching datatable-help for "multicore"](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/template/NamlServlet.jtp?macro=search_page&node=2315188&query=multicore).