# Ways to add multiple columns to data frame using plyr/dplyr/purrr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, plyr, purrr

I often have a need to mutate a data frame through the additional of several columns at once using a custom function, preferably using parallelization. Below are the ways I already know how to do this.

**Setup**

```
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
library(purrr)
library(doMC)
registerDoMC(2)

df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10), z = rnorm(10))
```

Suppose that I want two new columns, `foocol = x + y` and `barcol = (x + y) * 100`, but that these are actually complex calculations done in a custom function.

**Method 1: Add columns separately using `rowwise` and `mutate`**

```
foo <- function(x, y) return(x + y)
bar <- function(x, y) return((x + y) * 100)

df_out1 <- df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(foocol = foo(x, y), barcol = bar(x, y))
```

This is not a good solution since it requires two function calls for each row and two "expensive" calculations of `x + y`. It's also not parallelized.

**Method 2: Trick `ddply` into rowwise operation**

```
df2 <- df
df2$id <- 1:nrow(df2)

df_out2 <- ddply(df2, .(id), function(r) {
  foocol <- r$x + r$y
  barcol <- foocol * 100
  return(cbind(r, foocol, barcol))
}, .parallel = T)
```

Here I trick `ddply` into calling a function on each row by splitting on a unique `id` column I just created. It's clunky, though, and requires maintaining a useless column.

**Method 3: `splat`**

```
foobar <- function(x, y, ...) {
  foocol <- x + y
  barcol <- foocol * 100
  return(data.frame(x, y, ..., foocol, barcol))
}

df_out3 <- splat(foobar)(df)
```

I like this solution since you can reference the columns of `df` in the custom function (which can be anonymous if desired) without array comprehension. However, this method isn't parallelized.

**Method 4: `by_row`**

```
df_out4 <- df %>% by_row(function(r) {
  foocol <- r$x + r$y
  barcol <- foocol * 100
  return(data.frame(foocol = foocol, barcol = barcol))
}, .collate = "cols")
```

The `by_row` function from [purrr](https://github.com/hadley/purrr) eliminates the need for the unique `id` column, but this operation isn't parallelized.

**Method 5: `pmap_df`**

```
df_out5 <- pmap_df(df, foobar)
# or equivalently...
df_out5 <- df %>% pmap_df(foobar)
```

This is the best option I've found. The `pmap` family of functions also accept anonymous functions to apply to the arguments. I believe `pmap_df` converts `df` to a list and back, though, so maybe there is a performance hit.

It's also a bit annoying that I need to reference all the columns I plan on using for calculation in the function definition `function(x, y, ...)` instead of just `function(r)` for the row object.

---

Am I missing any good or better options? Are there any concerns with the methods I described?

Comment: You really shouldn't load `plyr` *after* loading `dplyr`. It gives a warning that you should listen to.

Comment: You could play with `purrr::invoke` and its variants, e.g. `invoke(foobar, df)` (equivalent to `do.call(foobar, df)`). Really it's usually a good thing if you need to reference which columns get passed to what parameters, though, or you can make mistakes silently.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, Method 1 does not require `rowwise()`.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `data.table`?

```
library(data.table)

foo <- function(x, y) return(x + y)
bar <- function(x, y) return((x + y) * 100)

dt <- as.data.table(df)

dt[, foocol:=foo(x,y)]
dt[, barcol:=bar(x,y)]
```

The `data.table` library is quite fast and has at least some [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013007/using-data-table-with-multiple-threads-in-r) potential for parallelization.